# Swift 3 - Display subview from UICollectionViewCell on fullscreen

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uikit

I have a subview (`gallery`, of type `UICollectionView`) inside a `UICollectionViewCell` **(A)** that I would like to display in full screen.

By doing so, inside (A):

```
if let keyWindow = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow {

    gallery.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
    keyWindow.bringSubview(toFront: gallery)
    gallery.frame = keyWindow.frame
}
```

the `gallery`'s frame value is correctly set to its new value but is wrongfully displayed ***behind (A)'s `collectionView`***. I want it to be full screen, i.e. "in front of every other view in the app".

What am I missing here in order to achieve desired behavior?

Comment: Don't try to add things to the app's `.keyWindow`. Instead, look into using `presentViewController` to show your "full screen view".

Comment: @DonMag: I did not state it there, but the idea is to expand this subview from the cell to full screen on user tap, and then shrink it back to the cell on second user tap when in full screen. Does that sound like achievable behavior with what you'd propose?

Comment: Here's a good tutorial / example of one way to do what you want. It has small images in a scroll view (equivalent to collection view)... tapping an image presents a new view controller, "zooming it out" from the tapped image. Perfect starting point! https://www.raywenderlich.com/146692/ios-animation-tutorial-custom-view-controller-presentation-transitions-2

Comment: @DonMag: looks indeed like a good start. Thanks a lot for the pointer !